# WP +WPML In edit.php show posts only those that belong to the logged in user & update filter count

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am trying to filter posts to only show those that belong to the logged in user. And I am using WMPL translation plugin. The problem is that if I filter out posts I still see the filter count for all posts and all languages on edit.php page at the top of the page.

[image: Filter count example img]

In the img above I wrote what should the real numbers be according to my database. Only Mine(9) is correct - I have 9 posts counting in all languages.

In the table itself is everything ok, it only shows logged in user posts even if I select All(12) filter I only see 9 posts. So how could I update the filters to count correctly?

I am using this code in my child theme functions.php to filter the posts:

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
  global $pagenow;

  if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin ){
    return $query;
  }
      

  if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
      global $user_ID;
      $query->set('author', $user_ID );
  }
  return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so hope this will help someone in the future, this is the solution that I came up with:

First I unset the All filter which shows all posts from all users and I am left only with the view of my own posts.

Code goes to child theme functions.php

```
 /*remove All and Published counts from edit.php list of posts */
add_filter('views_edit-objektai', 'custom_editor_counts');
add_filter('views_edit-marsrutai', 'custom_editor_counts');


function get_user_role() {
  global $current_user;

  $user_roles = $current_user->roles; 
  $user_role = array_shift($user_roles); 

  return $user_role;
}


function custom_editor_counts($views) {
  $user_role = get_user_role();
  if($user_role === 'author'){
    unset($views['all']);
    unset($views['publish']);
  }
  return $views;
}
```

Then I was looking for a WPML hook to edit those language filter counters but I did not found a hook for that. So I edited the plugin directly. So these changes will only help me until I update the plugin...

The function responsible for this lives in: \wp-content\plugins\sitepress-multilingual-cms\menu\post-menus\wpml-post-language-filter.class.php

The function name is get_count_data();

I changed to this:

```
protected function get_count_data( $type ) {
    $extra_conditions = $this->extra_conditions_snippet();
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles; 
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

      if($user_role === 'author'){
        return $this->wpdb->get_results( $this->wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT language_code, COUNT(p.ID) AS c
            FROM {$this->wpdb->prefix}icl_translations t
            JOIN {$this->wpdb->posts} p
                ON t.element_id=p.ID
                    AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', p.post_type)
            WHERE p.post_type=%s AND p.post_author = %d {$extra_conditions}
            ", $type, $user_id ) ); // added extra filter in this query
      }
    

    return $this->wpdb->get_results( $this->wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT language_code, COUNT(p.ID) AS c
            FROM {$this->wpdb->prefix}icl_translations t
            JOIN {$this->wpdb->posts} p
                ON t.element_id=p.ID
                    AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', p.post_type)
            WHERE p.post_type=%s {$extra_conditions}
            ", $type ) ); // left the default query for all the rest user roles
}
```

As I said this will work until the plugin update, so if anyone knows a better solution, please feel free to share.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else facing the same issue, I looked into it following Viktoras's take on it to figure out a solution. So I came up with this (not thogoughly tested, but it seems to work):

First, create a new class that will calculate and load the mumbers correctly. It is identical to the one in \wp-content\plugins\sitepress-multilingual-cms\menu\post-menus\wpml-post-language-filter.class.php with the only difference being what Viktoras mentions. So we create a new file, e.g. wpml-post-language-filter-new.php :

```
class WPML_Post_Language_Filter_NEW extends WPML_Language_Filter_Bar {
// ....... 
        protected function get_count_data( $type ) {
        $extra_conditions = $this->extra_conditions_snippet();
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        
        global $current_user;
        $user_roles = $current_user->roles; 
        $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

        if($user_role === 'author'){
            return $this->wpdb->get_results( $this->wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT language_code, COUNT(p.ID) AS c
                FROM {$this->wpdb->prefix}icl_translations t
                JOIN {$this->wpdb->posts} p
                    ON t.element_id=p.ID
                        AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', p.post_type)
                WHERE p.post_type=%s AND p.post_author = %d {$extra_conditions}
                ", $type, $user_id ) ); // added extra filter in this query
          }
    

        return $this->wpdb->get_results( $this->wpdb->prepare("
            SELECT language_code, COUNT(p.ID) AS c
            FROM {$this->wpdb->prefix}icl_translations t
            JOIN {$this->wpdb->posts} p
                ON t.element_id=p.ID
                    AND t.element_type = CONCAT('post_', p.post_type)
            WHERE p.post_type=%s {$extra_conditions}
            ", $type ) ); // left the default query for all the rest user roles
    }
//..........

}
```

Then we need to stop the original object from being used and instantiate a new one using the class we've just created:

```
//Remove 'language_filter', which has been enqueued with the use of 'js_load', which has been added to admin_enqueue_scripts in sitepress.class.php. Then create new object.
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    global $sitepress, $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) {
        remove_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $sitepress, 'language_filter') );
        if($sitepress) {
            require_once get_stylesheet_directory().'/wpml-post-language-filter-new.php';
            $post_lang_filter = new WPML_Post_Language_Filter_NEW( $sitepress->wpdb, $sitepress );
            $post_lang_filter->register_scripts();
            return $post_lang_filter->post_language_filter();

        }
    }
}, 2);
```